# makefile error "No rule to make target" how to solve it?

Tags: linux, make, cmake

what's wrong with my makefile?

```
CC = gcc
OBJS = main.o map.o extended_map.o election.o utilities.o
EXEC = election
DEBUG_FLAG = -DNDEBUG
COMP_FLAG = -std=c99 -Wall -pedantic-errors -Werror

$(EXEC) : $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(DEBUG_FLAG) $(OBJS) -o $@
main.o: main.c map.h election.h test_utilities.h
    $(CC) -c $(DEBUG_FLAG) $(COMP_FLAG) $*.c
map.o: map.c map.h utilities.h
    $(CC) -c $(DEBUG_FLAG) $(COMP_FLAG) $*.c
extended_map.o: extended_map.c extended_map.h map.h utilities.h
    $(CC) -c $(DEBUG_FLAG) $(COMP_FLAG) $*.c
election.o: election.c election.h map.h extended_map.h utilities.h
    $(CC) -c $(DEBUG_FLAG) $(COMP_FLAG) $*.c
utilities.o: utilities.c utilities.h
    $(CC) -c $(DEBUG_FLAG) $(COMP_FLAG) $*.c
clean:
    rm -f $(OBJS) $(EXEC)
```

I am running the following command on linux:

```
-bash-4.2$ ls
election.c  extended_map.c  main.c  makefile  mtm_map           utilities.c
election.h  extended_map.h  main.o  map.h     test_utilities.h  utilities.h
-bash-4.2$ make
make: *** No rule to make target `map.c', needed by `map.o'.  Stop.
-bash-4.2$
```

map.c exists inside a folder named `mtm_map` inside the current folder

Comment: Please do not deface your post. If you no longer need it, simply click the "delete" link on it.

Answer (score 1):

Your make rule for building `map.o` is expecting an input file called `map.c` *in the current* directory. You said this file actually lives in the `mtm_map` directory so your make rule should say:

```
map.o: mtm_map/map.c map.h utilities.h
    $(CC) -c $(DEBUG_FLAG) $(COMP_FLAG) $*.c
```